# Can't understand the proper to use Paypal's IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

As title says I don't understand how to use IPN.

This page
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/
says that I need to implement my IPN Listener and they provide samples.
This is the sample for PHP:

IPN.php

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
    /** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
    private $use_local_certs = true;
    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';
    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }
    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }
        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And they also provide an example:

Example.php

```
<?php 
namespace Listener;
require('PaypalIPN.php');
use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */
}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
?>
```

## What I'm trying to do:

I'm going to have Paypal buttons on my page to let users pay for a subscription based software (1/3/6/12 months). (They don't subscribe, they only pay the money needed for 1/3/6/12 months).
I need to automate the process where I update the subscription expiration date on my DB after I get the payment.

## My questions:

1. I don't get what do I have to edit, is the IPN.php meant to be uploaded on the server as it is provided?
2. Is it secure as it is?
3. Where should I point the Notification URL (on Paypal's IPN settings), to IPN.php or my edited version of Example.php?
4. Apart from this, any tips?

I want to clarify that I already read what's on paypal guide but I got lost with so much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** The code you have displayed is defining a class, so you can initiate an connection-instance, where you define different variables. So you shouldn't change that. You should upload it to your server and use it accordingly.

**2)** Ehm... That is a broad question. Like... Is a chain mail safe? Safe for people attacking you with a sword: Yes. Safe for people dropping nukes on you: No. And it also depends on how you use the chain mail.

But if I should try and answer the question that I think you're asking:

The script makes a safe connection to PayPal, yes. So you need to ensure, in the solution that you're making, that the script and your API-key is not stolen/abused; so people could access PayPal through your solution, doing stuff that you don't want them to do.

**3)** According to the [documentation that you linked to](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/), then:

> When you have completed your listener, push it to your site and specify the listener URL or notification URL in your account settings. See [IPN Setup](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) for more information.

... I must admit that I haven't used this before. But it looks like [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#dynamically-setting-the-notification-url) that is a way to pass notifications between your website and Paypal. So I assume that it's a path, that Paypal checks to get notifications, that will be displayed, ehm... somewhere(?). Sorry for the vague answer on this point.

**4)** My tip would be, to see if there are a solution (framework or something) that has the integration already. I think I would use Laravel or WordPress, if it was me, - but that's only because that is the tools the I'm confident using. But the both come with solutions ([Laravel](https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-695063599449) and [WordPress](https://woocommerce.com/)) that are being maintained by people who (hopefully) know what they're doing. So that if PayPal comes out with a new API, deprecating the one you're using now, - that you don't necessarily have to start back at the documentation again. But getting to know a framework takes quite a bit of time (just a heads up).

However, - it all comes down to what you're trying to make. So the TL;DR-version of this fourth point: Use a framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot. About point 2 you are right, it's too broad. What I meant was if I needed to validate the data, or something. But I think the answer is pretty obvious :D. Thank you for helping